# Retrieve key vault in web activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure Data Factory and I am now stuck at last step to finish my current task.

There are few REST API's that I need to call from ADF using Web Activity but before I make to REST API POST call, in this POST call I need to pass user credentials to be fetched from key vault and passing into BODY section. Once this POST request is issued I need to get authentication token from that server, hence as it is working in hard coded fashion.
But now I want to fetch userId and password from Azure Key Vault and I then need to pass it to Web Activity.

NOTE : I do not want to use MSI option.

Could you please help on retrieving userId and password from Azure Key Vault for Web Activity to pass this as part of authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow these steps to achieve what you want:

1. Save the userid and password in the azure keyvault. And then give your azure datafactory authority to access the keyvault:

I think you know how to add keyvault value, so I just show how to give the access authority.
[image]

[image]

[image]

And choose 'Add'. And dont foeget to save the edit.

2. The second step is about the web activity in ADF. You should create a web activity first.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then, you can use a Set variable activity to get the value.

[image]

The value of the activity is `@activity('yourwebactivityname').output.value`

This is my pipeline:

[image]

And I can get the value:

[image]

For more information, please have a look of the below document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities

Comment: I have checked this and it is issuing GET request using MSI authentication, I do not want to use MSI, I need to pass user credentials in POST request with user/pwd and other details wrapped into body section. and want to replace user/pwd values from key vault on runtime

Comment: @CSharpDev Why you dont want to use MSI? First, if you store the user/password in the keyvault, you must through the AD autherize to get the ad token. If you dont want to use MSI, you need to create a new service principal to get the ad token and let this to access. Any way, ad autherize can not skip.

Comment: @CSharpDev If you dont use the AD autherize to get the ad token, then you can not get the value of keyvault.

Comment: in a key vault under the access policy I have authorized my ADF, hence I want to read secrets directly into web activity using connection, now I don't know how connections works and how they connect to key vault to retrieve secrets?